# The STS couldn't understand my hateoas import and report error

Tags: spring-boot, spring-hateoas

I was building a RESTful service according to the official tutorial of Spring. I add the dependency as instructed, but the STS(Spring Tool Suite) couldn't figure out my function.

The STS couldn't understand `methodOn()` or `lintTo()` and keeps on giving errors,please help me with it.
**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**Controller:**

```
@GetMapping("/employees/{id}")
Resource<Employee> one(@PathVariable Long id) {

    Employee employee = repository.findById(id)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new EmployeeNotFoundException(id));

    return new Resource<>(employee,
        linkTo(methodOn(EmployeeController.class).one(id)).withSelfRel(),
        linkTo(methodOn(EmployeeController.class).all()).withRel("employees"));
}
```

Comment: Which errors did it give?

Comment: The method methodOn(Class<EmployeeController>) is undefined for the type EmployeeController and also the linkTo()

Comment: As per your detail i dont see error. what is tha error? methodOn() is part of which class? where is your object of that class?

Comment: methodOn() and linkTo() should both be included in hateoas,and I already add the dependency,but still error

Answer (score 14):

The import has been updated.

```java
import static org.springframework.hateoas.server.mvc.WebMvcLinkBuilder.*;
```